# How do I improve the python script speed when I want to insert a lot of values into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am currently working on a script, and I need to insert a value for each key in a dictionary containing large-scale data

```
for key, value in dict.items():
      score = somefunction(value)
      value.append(score)
```

the dictionary has nearly 100 thousands keys so it takes a lot of time to compute..

My friend says "value.append" takes too much time.
If it does not work with value.append,
how can I improve this script to boost the speed for computation?
(I have searched on the internet and it seems that a lot of people use value.append under this situation)

Your answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: If your dictionary contains lists, there is no way to improve this significantly...

Comment: 100 thousand isn’t that many. Have you measured timings here? Are you sure it isn’t `somefunction` taking the time?

Comment: Yes my idea exactly: 100k should be updated with lightspeed

Comment: it takes me 4 hours to run only 7 thousands data.....

Comment: i think i have to figure out how to improve the calculation in the function..

Comment: the reason why "append()" is slow, is because it is a linked list structure, and every memory is allocated per append().   All these are slow.   SInce you are successively appending it one after another, why not just preallocate from upfront an array:   then just increment an index to add to subsequent element of the array:   this will be much faster, as there are no link list construction + no allocation of memory per adding of element.   but u need to know upfront total size.

Comment: @PeterTeoh: That’s completely incorrect. `list` isn’t even a linked list.

Comment: Yes, Ryan was correct that my previous statement was incorrect.   List is implemented as a linear array of preallocated memory + randomly allocated memory, as explained here:

http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/ and this
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/09/why-python-is-slow/
And the latter link also explained python is slow for other reasons as well:   no single answer given, but multiple recommendations given within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value.append` is not slow by itself, in fact it has an amortized O(1) runtime.
The problem is in your algorithm itself, as far as I can tell, you have 100k different lists for which you compute a different score and update one by one. If all your lists are unique, I'm afraid there is no way to improve the speed, except for fundamentally changing the way you store the scores.

Regardless, I'm afraid your bottleneck is in your `some_function` with which you calculate the score, since iterating through 100k lists should be trivial. Once you start going over more lists though (in the million/billions),  you might want to think of another way. Could you post the function here?

If your lists are identical, it might be a good idea to create one main list and save it to every key. Then, because every key references the **same list**, changing the list for one of the keys will change it for every other key.